# Rails resize uploaded images with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am letting a user upload images with Paperclip gem.
However, I want to give them the ability to resize the image after they uploaded it.

Is there any tool for that? Any processor for Paperclip to help me implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look on this: [Image resizing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=asciicast)

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip uses imagemagick, check your distro's repos on how to install it [paperclip reference](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor)

From the model side it's quite easy, paper clip has a [quick start section](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start) to help you